# Can I get touch position and mouse position at once in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to get the position of the first touch on a mobile device AND the position for the mouse with the same code in unity?

```
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        _previousMousePos = Input.mousePosition; // average of all touches ?
    }
```

I've read that Input.MousePosition will give you the average of all touches, which is not I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Input.mousePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html) doesn't give you the average position of all touches, only the position of the mouse (if any), nothing more. Use [Input.touches](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-touches.html) to collect data about touch events (on supported devices).

```
private Vector3 lastMousePosition;
private Vector2 lastTouchPosition;

void Update()
{
   lastMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;

   if (Input.touchCount > 0)
      lastTouchPosition = Input.touches[0].position;
   else 
      lastTouchPosition = Vector2.Zero;
}
```

Comment: hey! thanks for the answer. You sure about that? I was under the impression that by default mousePosition would give you some touch data: ihttps://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-simulateMouseWithTouches.html

Comment: Like the documentations says, this options allow the simulation of mouse buttons via touch events, not the mouse position.